# Form with Rails + Slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

Having this on routes.rb

```
namespace :admin, :path => 'admin' do 
  resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :update]
end
```

and having created an update function in the controller:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.name = params[:name].presence
  @exercise.save!
end
```

How can I create a form with **Slim** and send a `PATCH` to the backend to modify this model?

For some reason I'm receiving a

`No route matches [POST] "/admin/user/5527984339613100031a0000"`

when trying to update an element. This is the code causing problems

```
= form_tag admin_user_path, method: :post do
  = submit_tag 'Save'
```

just to see the request in the developer console, which is not showed. Slim documentation on this is weak.

Comment: Just change `method: :post` to `method: :patch`. I suspect you also may need to specify the `@user` into `admin_user_path` i.e. `admin_user_path(@user)`

Comment: `form_tag` is a Rails helper method and has nothing to do with Slim. There is [very good documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) and [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) if you look in the right places.

Comment: You still not getting it. Slim is just a language like ERB or Haml. You use the form helpers in the exact same way you would in ERB, the syntax is just different.

Comment: Still not the point @max, but thanks. The point is I'm sending a valid url and for some reason the dispatcher is not routing properly.

`resources :user` should create the helpers, and since `:update` is allowed I can't see what's going wrong.

Comment: Your are not. You are setting the method to post not patch in your form. @sjagr allready pointed that out. You might want to read up on how rails with the help of rack fakes the extended HTTP verbs - 'method: :patch' just adds a hidden _method input to the form. Rack looks for it the request body and changes the request method to patch before it passes the request to rails.

Comment: @max Correct! The hint is in the error itself "No route matches **[POST]**"

Comment: @max is right. This has nothing to do with Slim. @A.Unger, to help you debug, you can run `rake routes | grep user` to see what your valid routes are and what (if any) params they expect - such as the likely `user_id` param for `admin_user_path`.

Comment: @A.Unger did you get your issue resolved?